# How can I convert this string to NSString?

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, hex, type-conversion

I got the following UUID values:

`0x70, 0x29, 0x78, 0x89, 0x64, 0xc4, 0x47, 0x67, 0xa1, 0x9a, 0x4a,
0x9f, 0xe4, 0x2b, 0xf9, 0x05`

This is the **encoding function** that the hardware developer has used:

```
const UUID MY_SERVICE_UUID = createUuid({ 0x70, 0x29, 0x78, 0x89, 0x64, 0xc4, 0x47, 0x67, 0xa1, 0x9a, 0x4a, 0x9f, 0xe4, 0x2b, 0xf9, 0x05 });
```

I think this is expressed in hex. Is this correct?

I need to translate the above to a `NSString` in order to use it. Any help in doing so?

Comment: What do you want at the end: @"702978..." or the "interpreted value (for example, if it's in fact a `NSData` like)?

Comment: Show the data structure those bytes are contained within.  Also what encoding are they using?

Comment: I added the encoding function used by the hardware developer

Comment: OK show the declaration of `UUID` (which is presumably different from `uuid_t` for some reason).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like a hex representation of UUID bytes. If the bytes are in correct order, you could construct an `NSString` like this:

```
const unsigned char uuidBytes[] = {0x70, 0x29, 0x78, 0x89, 0x64, 0xc4, 0x47, 0x67, 0xa1, 0x9a, 0x4a, 0x9f, 0xe4, 0x2b, 0xf9, 0x05};
NSUUID *uuid = [[NSUUID alloc] initWithUUIDBytes:uuidBytes];
NSString *uuidString = [uuid UUIDString];
```

Comment: Thanks, Xcode tells me to remove "[ ]". Is this correct? I think I need to find the correct initialisation function of an unsigned array of characters..

Comment: @mm24 Ah, you're right, the `[]` go to the other side.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Btw I am impressed by your network profile 300k of reputation, top 0.01%. You must be working for some top company in Silicon Valley :-)

Comment: @mm24 :) I am no longer in Silicon Valley, but I did work for three obscure start-ups there. Good luck with your project!